# Make an iMacros variable based on website elements / error / text outputs

Tags: javascript, imacros

I want to make `WAIT SECONDS=` function dependant on a variable based on website's outputs (errors or no button).

**I'm trying to make the script do the following:**

1. Press the submit button (if there's no button, **skip the website and execute the rest of the script**)
2. If "you have to wait 5/6/7/8/etc minutes" error pops up, it has to store the shown up amount of minutes in `SET !VAR`
3. Use the stored variable as `WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR1}}`
4. Try to submit again when the time is up
5. Proceed to execute the rest of the script

   - If there's no error, skip the resubmit function and proceed to execute the rest of the script

I searched everywhere and honestly don't know where to begin and how to do it. I'd be very grateful if someone could guide me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Hum, "I searched everywhere", ah-ah...! Everything you want is Basic iMacros Functionality involving several Commands/Mechanisms, all perfectly documented in the Wiki and with many Examples on the iMacros Forum...

Comment: Removing the 'arrays' + 'autohotkey' Tags which are completely irrelevant for this Qt and only annoying for Users following those Tags... (Especially the 'autohotkey' one, I don't think anybody is following the 'arrays' one...)

Comment: And...?, 2 days later, any "Progress", any Follow-up...? Hint: Why did you select the 'javascript' Tag, and why did I "leave" it, while your OP doesn't mention anything about JS...? (But you'll need to mention your FCI (explained in my Profile) for me to help you, and to finish your previous Thread/Qt a bit "correctly" by posting an Update and/or your "Solution"... (I apply the same Forum Rules like on the iMacros Forum, to help Users... (except for Screenshots)))